# How to make exe from html files with build-it firefox browser

Tags: html, firefox, exe, cd

How can do that?
I need to build a learning CD with HTML and need to make it executable.
But only firefox supports this HTML, so how can I embed firefox and html into an exe file.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use portable firefox on the CD and set the homepage to the CD's HTML Source?

Comment: I need to make a package with all of those HTML so user can not see the source.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue for the goal you trying to archive, maybe you may consider different route to deliver it with a more proper approach? Such as making it live online, if offline only the solution then you may consider [Adobe Air](http://get.adobe.com/air/), however the Air is using WebKit engine so some of the FireFox features might not works.

So far I have not known any of Firefox embedding framework to executable '*.exe' file.

Another dirty workaround is download portable firefox, make the homepage your html file as @stuart mentioned. And wrapping all with [AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to be a exe executable shortcut but using WinSize to trim off the firefox frame.